# Proper Case up to first instance of ","

Tags: excel, vba

Totally stumped on this, I want to convert the Names in a column to proper case but I do not want to change there titles.

How to convert to proper case up to the first `,`

```
BOB FEGESON
Sally Ran, Ph.D.
GREG HYMAN, MA, CPCC
```

I Get

```
Bob Fegeson
Sally Ran, Ph.d.
Greg Hyman, Ma, Cpcc
```

Want

```
Bob Fegeson
Sally Ran, Ph.D.
Greg Hyman, MA, CPCC
```

Thanks

This converts to proper case if `If InStr(cell.Formula, ",") > 0`

```
Sub FindChr()
Dim rAcells As Range
Dim rLoopCells As Range
Dim lReply As Long
Dim myRange As Range
Dim cell As Range

'Set variable to needed cells
Set rAcells = Range("D2", Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
Set rAcells = rAcells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, xlTextValues)

Set myRange = Range("D2", Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))

For Each cell In myRange
    If InStr(cell.Formula, ",") > 0 Then

    "Cant Not Figure out what goes here"

    Else
        ' Convert to Proper Case
      For Each rLoopCells In rAcells
          rLoopCells = StrConv(rLoopCells, vbProperCase)
      Next rLoopCells
    End If
  Next cell
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
Sub FindChr()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim myRange As Range, cell As Range
    Dim tmpString As String
    Dim MyString As Variant
    Dim i As Long

    '~~> Change this to the relevant worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

    With ws
        Set myRange = .Range("D2", .Range("D" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp))

        For Each cell In myRange
            If InStr(1, cell.Formula, ",") Then
                MyString = Split(cell.Formula, ",")

                tmpString = StrConv(MyString(0), vbProperCase)

                For i = 1 To UBound(MyString)
                    tmpString = tmpString & "," & MyString(i)
                Next i

                cell.Formula = tmpString
            Else
                cell.Formula = StrConv(cell.Formula, vbProperCase)
            End If
        Next cell
    End With
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: I noticed that I am also getting Betty H.whitney and Hank O'day where I should have Betty H.Whitney and Hank O'Day`. Thanks –

Comment: I see that you have marked this as an answer. Does that mean that you have managed to achieve what you want as mentioned in the above comment? If not then try this. After you get `MyString(0)`, simply check for `'` or `.` and then split it again and the concatenate them after you have changed them to propercase.

Comment: No, sorry, that is me being less than clear, although you answer the question as I wrote (thank you) it. I will try your suggestions.

Comment: Siddharth this worked `cell.Formula = Application.WorksheetFunction.Proper(cell.Formula)` in place of `cell.Formula = StrConv(cell.Formula, vbProperCase)`. Thank you again for the Macro.